# Installing pwnat through makefile gives errors

Tags: linux, make

I'm fairly new to Linux, still learning.
I'm trying to install pwnat.

```
git clone https://github.com/samyk/pwnat
cd pwnat
sudo make
```

It prints:

```
gcc -Wall -Wshadow -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -D LINUX   -c -o socket.o socket.c
gcc -Wall -Wshadow -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -D LINUX   -c -o message.o message.c
gcc -Wall -Wshadow -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -D LINUX   -c -o strlcpy.o strlcpy.c
gcc -Wall -Wshadow -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -D LINUX   -c -o client.o client.c
gcc -Wall -Wshadow -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -D LINUX   -c -o packet.o packet.c
gcc -Wall -Wshadow -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -D LINUX   -c -o list.o list.c
gcc -Wall -Wshadow -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -D LINUX   -c -o destination.o     destination.c
gcc -Wall -Wshadow -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -D LINUX   -c -o udpserver.o udpserver.c
gcc -Wall -Wshadow -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -D LINUX   -c -o udpclient.o udpclient.c
gcc -Wall -Wshadow -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -D LINUX -o pwnat pwnat.c socket.o message.o strlcpy.o client.o packet.o list.o destination.o udpserver.o udpclient.o
```

and when I try to `sudo make install`:

```
make: *** No rule to make target 'install'.  Stop.
```

Answer (score 0):

`make install` is unnecessary. `make` builds the `pwnat` executable in the directory. You can then copy it to a more convenient location in your `$PATH`.